# recreate_versions! doesn't work with fog/s3 when version already exists

Tags: amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I've got a mounted uploader FileUploader which has a number of versions. A number of TIFF images have been uploaded, and the present versions haven't been correctly converted to JPEG/PNG, though their filenames are correct.

Having updated the FileUploader to correctly convert to JPEG/PNG, recreating versions works flawlessly on the local filesystem. When using the remote images on S3, even using the guide (https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Recreate-and-reprocess-your-files-stored-on-fog), any images that already exist don't get updated, though their timestamps do. If the versions stored on S3 are deleted, then the versions are created correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today and the link you referenced was updated 2 years ago with this:

> with carrierwave_backgrounder you need to set process_#{uploader}_upload flag to true, otherwise it won't generate versions.

So, it would be:

```
YourModel.find_each do |ym| 
  begin
    ym.process_your_uploader_upload = true # if you use carrierwave_backgrounder
    ym.your_uploader.cache_stored_file! 
    ym.your_uploader.retrieve_from_cache!(ym.your_uploader.cache_name) 
    ym.your_uploader.recreate_versions!(:version1, :version2) 
    ym.save! 
  rescue => e
    puts  "ERROR: YourModel: #{ym.id} -> #{e.to_s}"
  end
end
```

I just tested this and can confirm that even if the versions exist on your FOG storage (in my case S3), it will create new versions and overwrite them.